# How to use 'timeupdate' event listener to highlight text from audio?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events

I'm using the 'timeupdate' event listener to sync a subtitle file with audio.

It is working currently, but I'd like to adjust it to where it is just highlighting the corresponding sentence in a large paragraph instead of deleting the entire span and replacing it with just the current sentence. This is the sort of functionality I am trying to replicate: https://j.hn/lab/html5karaoke/dream.html (see how it only highlights the section that it is currently on).

This is made complicated due to timeupdate constantly checking multiple times a second.

Here is the code:

```
var audioSync = function (options) {
  var audioPlayer = document.getElementById(options.audioPlayer);
  var subtitles = document.getElementById(options.subtitlesContainer);
  var syncData = [];

  var init = (function () {
    return fetch(new Request(options.subtitlesFile))
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then(createSubtitle);
  })();

  function createSubtitle(text) {
    var rawSubTitle = text;
    convertVttToJson(text).then((result) => {
      var x = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i].part && result[i].part.trim() != '') {
          syncData[x] = result[i];
          x++;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  audioPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (e) {
    syncData.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
      if (
        audioPlayer.currentTime * 1000 >= element.start &&
        audioPlayer.currentTime * 1000 <= element.end
      ) {
        while (subtitles.hasChildNodes()) {
          subtitles.removeChild(subtitles.firstChild);
        }

        var el = document.createElement('span');
        el.setAttribute('id', 'c_' + index);
        el.innerText = syncData[index].part + '\n';
        el.style.background = 'yellow';
        subtitles.appendChild(el);
      }
    });
  });
};
new audioSync({
  audioPlayer: 'audiofile', // the id of the audio tag
  subtitlesContainer: 'subtitles', // the id where subtitles should show
  subtitlesFile: './sample.vtt', // the path to the vtt file
});
```